# Dropbox writes files owned by root on server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, user-permissions, dropbox

Basically, we have Dropbox running on a server to keep some files synced.

It works nicely, except when Dropbox has to write the files itself. It keeps writing them as root, and my webserver cannot serve these files later on.

The current fix is a manual `chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html`, but it's unnecesary and cumbersome, with the server users having to call me to fix it each time they get forbidden.

So, the question is, how do I make dropbox write files as user/group `apache`?

Software: CentOS 5.6, daemonized dropbox server, apache

Answer (score 6):

Well, first off, using Dropbox as a deployment-platform is a bad idea. There are more suited tools to do this, I'm thinking about `rsync` and/or `git`...

Nevertheless, you probably installed DropBox with the root-user. Don't do this, install it as the apache-user. The deamon will run under the apache-user and will create files that apache has rights to read/write.

Open up the deamon-script, you will see it's just running `dropbox.py`. Edit this to run under apache and not under root.

But, and I can't stress this enough, you should be on the lookout for better alternatives.

Comment: +1 for both "Don't install it as `root`" and "Find something better" -- [rsync](http://everythinglinux.org/rsync/), [git](http://git-scm.com/), [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/), [chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/), [radmind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/radmind/), [etc…](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software)

Comment: rsync and git (as well as what voretaq7 suggested) do not meet our basic demands, add significant maintenance costs or are bloated with features we don't need. Trust me, I know my needs.

Comment: Then, while we're at it, why not write a script to change the owner of all files in `/var/www/html` and put in `crontab` and run it every minute?

Comment: There is a better way to achieve what you need: Don't use DropBox on a server. Try Capistrano or Fabric if you need a deployment tool.

Comment: Why not just do things the right way instead of trying to compound one bodge with another.

And security should *always* be of great importance. Sheesh

Comment: @ChristianSciberras Wow - you need to learn how to deal with people who are trying to help you. That's a pretty bad attitude you have there, bud.

Comment: @ChristianSciberras Sometimes the right answer is "You're doing it wrong". If you can't accept that, perhaps this isn't the site best suited for you.

Comment: @ChristianSciberras If it matches all your needs, then you wouldn't be posting this question, would you?

Comment: Just because something meets your needs does not mean you should use it. I could use a tank to drive to the shops but, as much as I'd like to, it's not the best idea, is it? "Best practices" and all that.

Comment: Let me put this in other terms: Dropbox doesn't really have anything fancy for setting file permissions and ownership, because it's meant for syncing pdf files and vacation pictures. Real deployment tools on the other hand...

Comment: A tank, while it could be driven to the shops, is not the best tool suited to the job. Dropbox, likewise, may work, but is also not the best tool for the job. Point aside, there's better ways of doing what you want to do.

Comment: That's it. I'm not answering anymore, it's obvious this is getting into useless trolling.